# Reading Properties file in Java

Tags: java, properties

I have the following code trying to read a properties file:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();           
InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("myProp.properties");
prop.load(stream);
```

I get an exception at the last line. Specifically:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
at Assignment1.BaseStation.readPropertyFile(BaseStation.java:46)
at Assignment1.BaseStation.main(BaseStation.java:87)
```

thanks,
Nikos

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Based on your exception, the `InputStream` is null, this means the class loader is not finding your properties file. I'm guessing that myProp.properties is in the root of your project, if that's the case, you need a preceding slash:

```
InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("/myProp.properties");
```

Comment: my file hierarchy is: src -> myPackage -> myClass.java , myProp.properties. I did what you advised me but it still throws the same exception

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` searches for the file on the classpath. If your properties file is in the package directory of `myPackage`, then use `/myPackage/myProp.properties` as the path.

Comment: @Mark Elliot what if I have a `conf` package to store all my configuration files and my file hierarchy is: `myproject ->src, conf, test` ,how am i gonna load the properties by adding a preceding slash?

Answer (score 69):

You can find information on this page:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
try {
    //load a properties file from class path, inside static method
    prop.load(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

    //get the property value and print it out
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the `Reader` in `prop.load(reader)`, according to the documentation: `The specified stream remains open after this method returns`

Comment: There are many methods in that link. Why did you choose the one with class loader? Are there any advantages or disadvantages of that method?

Answer (score 30):

You can use `ResourceBundle` class to read the properties file.

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myProp.properties");
```

Comment: ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myProp");

Comment: This approach is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978415/properties-vs-resource-bundle) for i18n.

Comment: I had no idea java had such util class.

Answer (score 26):

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

try {
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("conf/filename.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`conf/filename.properties` base on project root dir

Comment: My use case is for Jenkins so it's nice to have a solution that doesn't rely upon a bunch of ClassPathLoader shenanigans. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I see that the question is an old one. If anyone stumbles upon this in the future, I think this is one simple way of doing it. 
Keep the properties file in your project folder.

```
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("Config.properties");

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(reader);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't use *this* keyword like -

```
props.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("myProps.properties"));
```

in a static context.

The best thing would be to get hold of application context like -

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml");
```

then you can load the resource file from the classpath -

```
//load a properties file from class path, inside static method
        prop.load(context.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
```

This will work for both static and non static context and the best part is this properties file can be in any package/folder included in the application's classpath.

Comment: ApplicationContext is available only in case of Spring application

Answer (score 7):

Your file should be available as `com/example/foo/myProps.properties` in classpath. Then load it as:

```
props.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("myProps.properties"));
```

Answer (score 6):

if your config.properties is not in src/main/resource directory and it is in root directory of the project then you need to do somethinglike below :-

```
Properties prop = new Properties();          
File configFile = new File(myProp.properties);
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(configFile);
prop.load(stream);
```

Answer (score 5):

Many answers here describe dangerous methods where they instantiate a file input stream but do not get a reference to the input stream in order to close the stream later. This results in dangling input streams and memory leaks. The correct way of loading the properties should be similar to following:

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try(InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myProp.properties")) {
        prop.load(fis);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to find the specified properties file");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

Note the instantiating of the file input stream in `try-with-resources` block. Since a `FileInputStream` is autocloseable, it will be automatically closed after the `try-with-resources` block is exited. If you want to use a simple `try` block, you must explicitly close it using `fis.close();` in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 4):

If your properties file path and your java class path are same then you should this.

**For example:**

> src/myPackage/MyClass.java
>
> src/myPackage/MyFile.properties

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("MyFile.properties");
prop.load(stream);
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the current answers show the `InputStream` being closed (this will leak a file descriptor), and/or don't deal with `.getResourceAsStream()` returning null when the resource is not found (this will lead to a `NullPointerException` with the confusing message, `"inStream parameter is null"`). You need something like the following:

```
String propertiesFilename = "server.properties";
Properties prop = new Properties();
try (var inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertiesFilename)) {
    if (inputStream == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(propertiesFilename);
    }
    prop.load(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
                "Could not read " + propertiesFilename + " resource file: " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the file name is correct and that the file is actually in the class path. `getResourceAsStream()` will return null if this is not the case which causes the last line to throw the exception.

If myProp.properties is in the root directory of your project, use `/myProp.properties` instead.

Comment: my file hierarchy is: src -> myPackage -> myClass.java , myProp.properties. I did what you advised me but it still throws the same exception

Comment: Since your properties file is not at the root of your project, you don't need the leading slash.

Comment: I was getting the exception thrown in the first place without the leading slash. It's still not working.

Answer (score 3):

Given the context `loader.getResourceAsStream("myPackage/myProp.properties")` should be used.

Leading `'/'` doesn't work with `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String)` method.

Alternatively you could use `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)` method, which uses `'/'` to determine if the path is absolute or relative to the class location.

***Examples:***

```
myClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myProp.properties")
myClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/myPackage/myProp.properties")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use java.io.InputStream to read the file as shown below:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(myProps.properties);
```

Comment: How to convert InputStream to File in java? I wanted to read .properties file using File API

Answer (score 2):

A good practice which is not state in previous solution is to passing properties especially the property files that generated in compile time with build plugins perhaps, is to Use   **PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer**

```
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propsConfig 
          = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propsConfig.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("myProp.properties"));
        propsConfig.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        propsConfig.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return propsConfig;
    }
```

then can accessing the properties from IOC as demand such

```
    @Value("${your.desired.property.pointer}")
    private String value;
```

Answer (score 1):

For Reading Properties file with its original order:

```
    File file = new File("../config/edc.properties");
    PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
    PropertiesConfigurationLayout layout = new PropertiesConfigurationLayout(config);
    layout.load(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

    for(Object propKey : layout.getKeys()){
        PropertiesConfiguration propval =  layout.getConfiguration();
        String value = propval.getProperty((String) propKey).toString();
        out.print("Current Key:" + propkey + "Current Value:" + propval + "<br>");
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Specify the path starting from src as below:

```
src/main/resources/myprop.proper
```