# properties lang.NullPointerException reading from same package

Tags: java, file-io, properties, configuration, nullpointerexception

I've tried variations on the path to the properties file, but can't seem to get it correct.

```
Here's the structure:

src/
├── properties.properties
└── teln
    ├── ConnectMUD.java
    ├── IOUtil.java
    └── PropertiesReader.java
```

and the error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at teln.PropertiesReader.getProps(PropertiesReader.java:16)
    at teln.ConnectMUD.main(ConnectMUD.java:18)
```

and the class in question:

```
package teln;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PropertiesReader {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(PropertiesReader.class.getName());
    private static Properties props = new Properties();

    public static Properties getProps() {
        try {
            props.load(PropertiesReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/teln/teln.properties"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PropertiesReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        LOG.fine(props.toString());
        return props;
    }
}
```

The project is `Teln` and the package is `teln` (not good choices, maybe).

see also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8285636/262852

Comment: Is it `teln.properties` or `properties.properties`?

Comment: try putting the properties file in the project root rather than the src folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code and setup don't match. You ask for a `teln.properties` file inside `teln`  but you show a `properties.properties` file outside of `teln`. Please be consistent in your question.

The javadoc for [`Class#getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) says it all.

The `ClassLoader` will look at the root of the classpath (you can define the classpath in your Netbeans configuration).

With a Netbeans setup like

```
src/
├── properties.properties
└── teln
    ├── ConnectMUD.java
    ├── IOUtil.java
    └── PropertiesReader.java
```

we can assume that the classpath root will be

```
properties.properties
teln/ConnectMud.class
teln/IOUtil.class
teln/PropertiesReader.class
```

If you want to get the `properties.properties` resource, you need to get it like so

```
 props.load(PropertiesReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/properties.properties"));
```

The prefixed `/` means to make the path relative to the root of the classpath. If you had ommited it, the method would have looked at the root of the package the class `PropertiesReader` is in.

Clue: If you are unsure what your classpath is, use Netbeans to compile a Jar of your project and look in there.

Comment: where *should* the properties file be?  in the root?

Comment: @Thufir It's all up to you. If the properties is only relevant to a certain class, put it in that class' package (and reference it correctly). If the properties file is important for the entire application, it should probably be either at root or in some package containing configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing

> props.load(PropertiesReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/Teln/teln.properties"));

with

> props.load(PropertiesReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/teln/teln.properties"));

Comment: There's no `teln.properties` file in the package `teln` in the description of the question.

Comment: oh ok, sorry I missed that but it is there in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
props.load(PropertiesReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/connection.properties"));
```

with this structure:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/Teln$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/Teln$ tree src/
src/
├── connection.properties
└── teln
    ├── ConnectMUD.java
    ├── IOUtil.java
    └── PropertiesReader.java

1 directory, 4 files
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/Teln$
```