# Converting Java properties file into JSON string

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm writing  a simple parser to convert a java properties file which contains entries in `name=value` pair to a `json` string. 
Below is the code. The code requires that each entry is in a new line:

```
      sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
        while ((sCurrentLine) != null)
        {                           
              config+=sCurrentLine.replace('=', ':');
              sCurrentLine = br.readLine()
              if(sCurrentLine!=null)
              config+=",";
        }
        config+="}";
```

The function works fine except in cases when there are extra empty new lines in the properties file. (Ex: Suppose I write the last entry in the props file and then hit two enters, the file will contain two empty new lines after the last entry) . While the expected output is `{name1:value1,name2:value2}` , in the above case when extra new lines are present , I get the output as `{name1:value1,name2:value2,}` . The number of trailing `,` increases with the number of empty new lines.

I know its because the `readLine()` reads the empty line while logically it shouldn't but how do I change this?

Comment: It is useless to parse property files, because Java can read them [out of the box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285595/reading-properties-file-in-java). And [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/pull/82) is the code to generate JSON from property objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be solved using the `contains()` method. Simply ensure the existence of a `"="` in your line..

```
while ((sCurrentLine) != null)
    {
          if(sCurrentLine.contains("=") {                           
              config+=sCurrentLine.replace('=', ':');
              sCurrentLine = br.readLine()
              if(sCurrentLine!=null)
                  config+=",";
          }
    }
```

**Example**

```
sCurrentLine = "name=dave"
if(sCurrentLine.contains("=")) // Evaluates to true.
      // Do logic.

sCurrentLine = ""
if(sCurrentLine.contains("=")) // Evaluates to false.
     // Don't do logic.

sCurrentLine = "\n"
if(sCurrentLine.contains("=")) // Evaluates to false.
     // Don't do logic.
```

> I know its because the readLine() reads the empty line while logically it shouldn't but how do I change this?

`readLine()` reads everything up to `\n`. That's how it can check for a new line. You've got `\n` and nothing before it, so your line will consist of `""` because `\n` is omitted.

**Slight enhancement**

If you want to make sure your line definitely has a name and a property in it, then you can use some simple regex.

```
if(s.CurrentLine.matches("\\w+=\\w+"))
// Evaluates to any letter, 1 or moe times, followd by an "=", followed by letters.
```

Comment: Thanks for the enhancement too needed that. Can't seem to think these days.

Comment: I do apologise! Yes it should be.

Answer (score 1):

One way is the use of method `trim()` to check is the current line empty or not:

```
  sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
    while ((sCurrentLine) != null)
    {                           
          If ("".equals(sCurrentLine.trim()) == false)
          {
            config+=sCurrentLine.replace('=', ':');
            sCurrentLine = br.readLine()
            if(sCurrentLine!=null)
            config+=",";
          }
    }
    config+="}";
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will check regex for empty line . this should also do

```
 if (sCurrentLine != null){
            if (!sCurrentLine.matches("^\\s*$"))  // matches empty lines
                    config += ",";
        }
```