# Can I share a properties file between java and javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

I need to have access to a properties file from within my java web application. So I would normally put this in my classpath somewhere, and load it using `getResourceAsStream("my.properties")`.

I also need to access the **same** properties file from within javascript. I know I could read this using an XHR if the file exists in the web resources folder, but in this case it does not.

What can I do here? I'm trying to avoid two copies of the file.

```
Project
- JavaSource
  - MyClass.java
  - my.properties
- WebContent
  - myjavascript.js
```

Comment: Leave the properties file where it is and write a Java API that JS would use through AJAX calls to access the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a Java service that [turns the properties file into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871694/java-properties-to-json). It's pretty easy to do, and something that I've done in a few projects. You can then just call it by AJAX or referencing it in a script tag.

Comment: And the motive for not to write the file in JSON to start with is ___________________?

Comment: ... Because the properties file already exists and I can't change the filetype.