# AngularJS : How can i convert .properties file in to json object

Tags: angularjs

I got a requirement to convert .properties file to JSON object using angular js.

I have no clue how to achive this, i searched in net but did not found the solution. Could you please help me with this.

.properties file contains

```
a.b.10=M
a.b.11=M50
a.b.12=M508
```

Output should be

```
{"a":{"b":{"10":"M","11":"M50","12":"M508"}}}
```

Comment: do you receive its content as a string?

Comment: Its a properties file and file contains key=value pair.

Comment: how do you get it into angularjs in the first place?  here is [the alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871694/java-properties-to-json), if that's what you are looking for

Comment: you can create a nested object from string with this: `object={}; "a.b.10=M".split("=")[0].split(".").reduce(function(o, s) { return o[s] = {}; }, object);`

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```js
var str1 = "a.b.12=M508";
var str2 = "a.b.10=M";
var str3 = "a.b.11=M50";
var result = {};

function createObject(str) {
    str.split('.').reduce((obj, key) => {
        if (!obj[key] && !key.includes('='))
            obj[key] = {};
        else if (key.includes('=')) {
            var keys = key.split('=');
            obj[keys[0]] = keys[1];
        }
        return obj[key];
    }, result);
    return result;
}
createObject(str1);
createObject(str2);
createObject(str3);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!!! however in this eg we have 3 key value pair. what if the properties file is appended with few more values. does that also require code update?