# How get Json format output when i have attributes in application.properties file using spring boot and restful

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I have below properties file

student.properties

```
firstname=John
lastname=Ryan
city=NewYork
```

If i want to get output in Json format how can i get it using springboot and restful?
To read student.properties i have used ConfigurationProperties    and   PropertySource and i got the output in plain text format only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java properties to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871694/java-properties-to-json)

Comment: Please describe your question by giving a complete and brief example.