# Add command-config option in AdminClient Kafka java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to put **conf.put("command-config", "client_security.properties");** as apart of configuration in my AdminClient for Kafka java, but its not working.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-377%3A+TopicCommand+to+use+AdminClient

Some help is provided here but not able to implement it

I have tried below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    AdminClient client = null;

        Map<String, Object> conf = new HashMap<>();
        conf.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "");
        conf.put(AdminClientConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
        client = AdminClient.create(conf);

    ListTopicsResult ltr = client.listTopics();
    KafkaFuture<Set<String>> names = ltr.names();
    System.out.println(names.get());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`--command-config` is a CLI argument only, not a AdminClient property

You can directly read your property file into a Properties object to accomplish the same thing

Comment: Thanks...Do you have any working example of that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285595/reading-properties-file-in-java/8285765