# Java Spring accesing property from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, properties-file

I have a entry on application.properties like this.

```
stackoverflow.questiontitle=I cant see this from environment
```

But in my code I'm unable to see it.

[image]

As you can see the @Value is working but this time I need it from Environment or ApplicationContext. How can I do that?

### Update

I mean the @Value I can see the property but I need it from Environment on other class, yes it is failing on runtime.

Is running prod profile.

Comment: Which environment is you application running? Usually you have environments like local, staging, prod. In which file is your properties and which environment are you running may give you the answer

Comment: Just to be clear is not working at runtime or is it something else?

Comment: You can't get a property from the `Environment` that is for OS environment variables. What you can do, is to define your property to come from the OS `Environment` like `stackoverflow.questiontitle=${OS_ENV_QUESTION_TITLE}` and make sure it exists on that environment.

Comment: Thanks Jorge all i want to do is get programmatically a entry from file application.properties any different that @Value is that possible?

Comment: Short answer, yes you can. Though if you are using a spring application I would not recommend it. It was designed this way so the framework can get you the values you need from the correct resources. Now if you still need to get that property you can always read the property file directly and then get it using load resources here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8285636/460557

Comment: You can also try injecting the Environment bean using @Autowired and then try reading the property.

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```java
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Component
class WithEnvironment {

    WithEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("stackoverflow.questiontitle"));
    }
}
```

To see the value in `IntelliJ IDEA` in debug mode you can use:

- `((ApplicationEnvironment)environment).getProperty("stackoverflow.questiontitle")`
- add a `New Class Level Watch...` on `environment` with `getProperty("stackoverflow.questiontitle")`

---

[image]

Comment: But i have tried with Environment variable and returns null.. i dont know why

Comment: @chiperortiz Try to find the property in debug mode (see picture answer)