# Why not use ResourceBundle instead of Properties?

Tags: java

This is an easy question to which I can't find a concluding answer.

I can load string properties (e.g.: a query for a prepared statement) from a `config.properties` file. Let's say I want to take the database connection to which to connect.

If I want to take this information from the file, I could do just the following in a class:

```
    private static final ResourceBundle BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle("scheduler");
    private static final String DRIVER  = BUNDLE.getString("bd.driver");
    private static final String CONNECTIONURL  =BUNDLE.getString("bd.url");
....
```

But instead I've seen that many people recommend using instead Properties, Then I would have to do the same with something like this (if I want to keep the class static and not have a proper constructor):

```
static {
        prop = new Properties(); 
        try {                prop.load(ReportsDB.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReportsDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    private static final String DRIVER  = prop.getProperty("bd.driver");
    private static final String CONNECTIONURL  = prop.getProperty("bd.url");
```

So, why shouldn’t I use the `ResourceBundle` instead of `Properties` when the second one is more verbose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So, why shouldn’t I use the ResourceBundle instead of Properties when the second one is more verbose?

Because that's not what `ResourceBundle` is for. The [description of the class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) starts with:

> Resource bundles contain locale-specific objects. When your program needs a locale-specific resource, a String for example, your program can load it from the resource bundle that is appropriate for the current user's locale. In this way, you can write program code that is largely independent of the user's locale isolating most, if not all, of the locale-specific information in resource bundles.

Does any of this sound like your use case? I don't think so.

It sounds like the problem is *purely* the verbosity of loading a properties file: so write a utility method to do that. Then your code can be simply:

```
private static final Properties CONFIGURATION = PropertyUtil.load("scheduler.properties");
private static final String DRIVER = CONFIGURATION.getString("bd.driver");
private static final String CONNECTIONURL = CONFIGURATION.getString("bd.url");
```

Admittedly I'm not keen on having static field initializers in an order-dependent way like that... I'd be tempted to encapsulate all of the configuration in a separate class, so you could write:

```
private static final SchedulerConfiguration CONFIG = 
    SchedulerConfiguration.load("scheduler.properties");
```

then use `CONFIG.getDriver()` etc which could fetch from the properties each time, or use a field, or whatever.

Comment: easy one but thanks for the explanation. Although I know is the intended purpose of the class, if it meets your requirements why not use it? is it slower? does it have any border case in which it could fail? maybe is pointless but I really want to know if there is any other reason

Comment: @ChristianVielma: Because it makes your code *look* like it's trying to achieve one thing, when really it's trying to do something else. *At least* hide this in a single place, and document why you're doing it - but ideally just use classes how they're *intended* to be used, and you'll get fewer surprises. (As will those reading your code.)

Answer (score 0):

One concrete difference is that `ResourceBundle.getBundle("scheduler")` will search for the file in the classpath (the src package folder for example). If you call `ResourceBundle.getBundle("myfile")` on an external file you will get the `MissingResourceException`.

If you want to use an external file (a file located in the project root for example) you can use the Properties class:

```
Properties configuration = new Properties();
try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("configuration.properties")) {
        configuration.load(input);
        System.out.println("Configuration value: " + configuration.getProperty("key"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```